# Google-Oauth authentication error

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, google-oauth, google-authentication

Getting the following error when trying to login with google -oauth.

```
I, [2014-04-23T10:08:24.349056 #4905]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.

I, [2014-04-23T10:08:24.861288 #4905]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.

I, [2014-04-23T10:08:28.637438 #4905]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.

E, [2014-04-23T10:08:30.207714 #4905] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, {"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"accessNotConfigured", "message"=>"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}: 

{

 "error": {

  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],

  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in your error log, Activate the Google API in developers settings in your account.

Comment: what is the link to do that?

Comment: The Google Developers Console is at https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0

Comment: Which API should be enabled? There is no such thing as "Google API", nor anything about "auth", or "credentials"..

Comment: @Cort3z the comment above you has the link to the landing page where you grant access to a project, similar to facebook api

Comment: @Babar Yes. You still did not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

*I found this question after some googling, and I was not very satisfied with @Babar's answer, as it id not actually resolve my problem.*

After a lot of digging around I found that you have to enable the `Google+ API` ([some also say](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/111) you need the `Contacts API`) in your developer console. I did not have to do this before, but apparently some change has come around.

To do so, do the following steps:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Select your project
3. Press "APIs & auth" from the side-panel
4. Press "APIs" from the dropdown
5. Find and enable `Google+ API` and `Contacts API`
6. After they are enabled, **`WAIT ABOUT 5 MINUTES`** for the APIs to kick in.

Now you should be able to use the Oauth2 login again.

Comment: this is much better answer...thanks finally I've got oauth2 with devise working

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a similar issue with my Rails app throwing error 403. So I resolved it by upgrading the omniauth gems by running `bundle update devise omniauth omniauth-google-oauth2` in the terminal.